# Chrome Extension change div content of a local page

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I have a local html page called "PageRedirect.html" for chrome extension that has a p tag with id called "toChange"

I have a function in background.js

```
function doRedirect(tab,val){

    var tabUrl = encodeURIComponent(tab.url);
    var tabTitle = encodeURIComponent(tab.title);
    // determine the type of redirection 

    if(val == 1 ){
        var redirectURL = chrome.extension.getURL('PageRedirect.html');
    }

    chrome.tabs.update(tab.id, {url: "redirectURL"});

}
```

This will successfully redirect the page I want.
However, if I want to dynamically p tag with id="toChange" content from blank to new string that I want.

What can I do in this case?
Is there any demo?
I tried message sending method but it has some problems locating the id.

Something like this

```
chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener(

    function(request, sender, sendResponse) 
    {
        if (request.warning == "true"){
            url = request.url;
            var elem = document.getElementById("toChange");  // elem will be undefined
        }   
    }
);
```

I am guessing the reason why it will be undefined is caused by the fact that PageRedirect.js is not the "document".